# How to get an external SWF to play on only one frame AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an external SWF file loading perfectly fine to my Flash site. However, once the frame has been viewed, it carries on running in other frames when I only want it to play on frame 6. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an amazingly vague question. Please elaborate on the situation (such as what your application does), and provide code if possible.

Comment: sorry im new to this.. Basically I am creating a flash website for a project. I have made an external image gallery and have saved that as a swf file. I am opening this file in my flash website externally. Here is the code I have got loading the external swf:

Comment: import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("AS3 Grid Gallery.swf");
myLoader.load(url);
addChild(myLoader);
myLoader.x = 40;
myLoader.y = 175;

Comment: so basically, when I click on the gallery page, it loads up the swf. when you go to a different page, the swf file keeps playing

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a ViewStack?  Make sure everything's embedded specifically into the right child of the ViewStack.  If that's not the problem, edit your answer (don't just comment) so as to take the code you mentioned in your comment, and not only show that, but also the code whose greater context it falls under (like the scope of the URLRequest).

Comment: Wont let me edit for some reason. No I am not using ViewStack. I was looking at removeChild(); but how would I implement this to stop the external swf from loading on frames 1,2,3,4,5?

Thanks

Comment: @DanielRees have you considered addin stop(); at the frames 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?